# read a text file in asset folder (phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, file-handling

I want to read a text file which is placed in my asset folder. i don't want to copy that file to /sdcard or phone memory. is it posible to read that file. if yes how.. please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy by using Ajax. Try below code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"myFile.txt", // relative path to www folder
    type:"get",
    contentType:"application/text",
    success: function(text){
        //todo: 
    }
});
```